# Lucas Chess Issues with Chess Openings

Tags: opening, learning, software

I am using Lucas Chess but its opening lines don't display appropriately. Here the engine doesn't show opening lines automatically. What opening book can I use with engine for preparation of absolute opening? Or, are there any opening apps for practicing openings?

Answer (score 2):

If you know what openings you want to play, you could input it into the [free Lichess analysis board](https://lichess.org/analysis). This will allow you to see what the most optimal moves are and also see the common replies from top-level games. You can also continue playing from a given opening position against the engine for practice.

If you don't know what opening specifically you would like to play, I highly recommend [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1857444191) to learn general opening skills.

Comment: Actually, I was a great fan of Kasparov when I started to play, and afterwards I followed his openings in the Fide-rated standard time control tournaments. But nowadays, it seems arduous to follow his openings.  .